# Require fingerprint to answer call?

Tags: settings, security, password, privacy

A friend has a problem with other people answering their phone and thereby intercepting their calls. Is anybody aware of an app, setting, or Android distro that requires a fingerprint swipe to answer an ordinary phonecall?

Google has not been helpful (or my google-fu is insufficient level, below 9000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Google Fu: ["android protect incoming calls"](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+protect+incoming+calls) turns up a bunch of apps to protect incoming calls. Most of them use PIN or pattern, though. So: [android protect incoming calls finger-print](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+protect+incoming+calls) → Hit #1 = **[AppLock 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree):**

> Android 5.1 supported, Samsung Fingerprint unlock supported
>
> […]
>
> ☆ **Lock Incoming Calls**

<sup>(My Google-Fu must be beyond level 9000 then :))</sup>

Hit #3 from that search might be worth reading as well: [How to Lock Any App with Fingerprint Security on Your Galaxy S5](http://gs5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/lock-any-app-with-fingerprint-security-your-galaxy-s5-0156353/). Not sure if all this is restricted to Samsung devices, though (and you didn't name yours).